# Null State Level 2 in CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, hilbert-space

I'm reading Cardy's notes on CFT. He states the following in section 4.3:

$$\hat L_n\left(\hat L_{-2}|\phi_j\rangle-(1/g)\hat{L^2}_{-1}|\phi_j\rangle\right)=0.$$

I tried to work this out explicitly and I managed to prove it for $n=1$ and $n=2$, but I can't figure this out for general $n$. After some manipulations I get stuck here:

$$((n+2)\hat L_{n-2}-(n+1)(1/g)\hat{L}_{n-1})\hat L_{-1}|\phi_j\rangle+(n+1)\hat L_{-1}\hat L_{n-1}|\phi_j\rangle.$$

How is this zero?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the subject or equations, I still smell a classic induction problem a mile away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use repeatedly:

1. The [Virasoro algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra).
2. The condition for being a [lowest weight representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra#Representation_theory).

Comment: yea it was actually pretty easy :) thanks for the hint